# HTML5 Carousel don't fit in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-5

So I used the carousel part of a HTML5 template that I saw in html5up.net, I put it in the website I'm doing using asp.net mvc. It works but when I'm hovering to the right arrow the last content of the carousel is just showing 1/4 of it. I don't know why. I'm not sure if the problem is in the CSS. So here's the CSS code of the carousel. Help me pleeease.

```
/* Carousel */

    .carousel {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

        .carousel .forward, .carousel .backward {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: 6em;
            height: 12em;
            margin-top: -6em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .carousel .forward:before, .carousel .backward:before {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 6em;
                height: 6em;
                border-radius: 100%;
                background-color: #6e6f74;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -3em;
                -moz-transition: background-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: background-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: background-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
                transition: background-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            }

            .carousel .forward:after, .carousel .backward:after {
                content: '';
                width: 3em;
                height: 3em;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                margin: -1.5em 0 0 0;
                background: url("images/arrow.svg") no-repeat center center;
            }

            .carousel .forward:hover:before, .carousel .backward:hover:before {
                background-color: #0066cc;
            }

        .carousel .forward {
            right: 0;
        }

            .carousel .forward:before {
                right: -3em;
            }

            .carousel .forward:after {
                right: -0.25em;
            }

        .carousel .backward {
            left: 0;
        }

            .carousel .backward:before {
                left: -3em;
            }

            .carousel .backward:after {
                left: -0.25em;
                -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
                transform: scaleX(-1);
            }

        .carousel .reel {
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
        }

        .carousel article {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 18em;
            background: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 1em 3em 1em;
            margin: 0 2em 0 0;
            white-space: normal;
            opacity: 1.0;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
        }

            .carousel article.loading {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            .carousel article .image {
                position: relative;
                left: -1em;
                top: 0;
                width: auto;
                margin-right: -2em;
                margin-bottom: 3em;
            }

            .carousel article p {
                text-align: center;
            }

/* Wide */

    @media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

        /* Carousel */

            .carousel {
                padding: 1.5em 0 1.5em 0;
            }

                .carousel .reel {
                    padding: 0 1.5em 0 1.5em;
                }

                .carousel article {
                    width: 18em;
                    margin: 0 1.25em 0 0;
                }

    }


/* Narrower */

    @media screen and (max-width: 840px) {


        /* Carousel */

            .carousel {
                padding: 1.25em 0 1.25em 0;
            }

                .carousel article {
                    width: 18em;
                    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
                }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {


        /* Carousel */

            .carousel {
                padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
            }

                .carousel .reel {
                    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
                }

                .carousel article {
                    width: 14em;
                    padding-bottom: 2em;
                    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
                }

                    .carousel article .image {
                        margin-bottom: 2em;
                    }

    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container">

    <h1>Circular Content Carousel<span>with jQuery</span></h1>
    <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
        <div class="ca-wrapper">
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Stop factory farming</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>The greatness of a nation and its moral progress can be judged by the way in which its animals are treated.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>Animals are not commodities</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Respect Life &amp; Rights</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>I hold that the more helpless a creature, the more entitled it is to protection by man from the cruelty of man.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>Would you eat your dog?</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Become 100% meat-free</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>I feel that spiritual progress does demand at some stage that we should cease to kill our fellow creatures for the satisfaction of our bodily wants.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>You can change the world</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Make a difference</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>A man is but the product of his thoughts what he thinks, he becomes.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>Think globally, act locally</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Say no to killing</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>A weak man is just by accident. A strong but non-violent man is unjust by accident.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>Animals have rights, too!</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Don't believe the lies</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>An error does not become truth by reason of multiplied propagation, nor does truth become error because nobody sees it.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>How essential is meat?</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>Save the planet</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>A small body of determined spirits fired by an unquenchable faith in their mission can alter the course of history.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>Collateral damage?</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
                <div class="ca-item-main">
                    <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                    <h3>It's time to move on</h3>
                    <h4>
                        <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                        <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h6>Let's finally become humans</h6>
                        <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                        <div class="ca-content-text">
                            <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                            <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Read more</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Share this</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Become a member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5>Quotes by Mohandas Gandhi</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, but with the HTML and CSS surrounding the carousel. Can you post a working example?

Comment: I include my Index.cshtml in my question. Thanks for the response. It's much appreciated. :)